# deleteCharAt() deleting more than one character from string in Java

Tags: java, stringbuilder

I am trying to delete some unwanted characters from a string. I am reaing in a .txt file and i want to remove all of the commas in the file. When I use deletCharAt() it deletes more than one char.
Here is an example of the .txt file:

```
1,2,0
3,4,5
6,7,8
```

Here is my code:

```
public String loadStartBoard(String filename) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));

     try {

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = reader.readLine();

        while (line != null) {
            sb.append(line);
            sb.append("\n");
            sb.deleteCharAt(1);
            //sb.deleteCharAt(2);
            //sb.deleteCharAt(5);
            //sb.deleteCharAt(6);
            //sb.deleteCharAt(9);
            //sb.deleteCharAt(10);

             line = reader.readLine();

        }
        startState = sb.toString();
        return startState;

    } finally {
        reader.close();
    }
}
```

---

This gives the output:

```
103,4,5
6,7,8
```

So sb.deleteCharAt(1) is removing ",2," as one char and I am not sure why. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: This could be easily explained if your file contained a second (blank) line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are deleting from the StringBuffer, thus you keep deleting the second character from the first line that you imported.

The easiest way to achieve this is to probably use a second StringBuilder:

```
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new StringReader("1,2,0\n3,4,5\n6,7,8"));

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String line = reader.readLine();

    StringBuilder currentLine = new StringBuilder();

    while (line != null)
    {
        currentLine.delete(0, currentLine.capacity());
        currentLine.append(line);
        currentLine.deleteCharAt(1);

        sb.append(currentLine.toString());
        sb.append("\n");

        line = reader.readLine();

    }
    System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

Note I've changed your `FileReader` to a `StringReader` for the sample code. You can easily change that back...